# How do I rename a button in a different View controller with a firebase username from a UIView cell?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to rename the "Add Bodyguard" button with a username from my firebase database when that user is selected from the cell

```
// Code for the contacts page where a user is selected from cell.


class ContactsTableViewController: UITableViewController { 
var ref: DatabaseReference!,
    posts = [eventsStruct]()

    let cellId = "cellId"
    var users = [CurrentUser]()


    struct eventsStruct {
        let email: String!
        let username: String!
        let phoneNumber: String!
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchUser()
    }

    func fetchUser() {
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("Users").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with:{(snapshot) in
            if let usersDictionary = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable:String]
            {
                let email = usersDictionary["email"]
                let username = usersDictionary["username"]
                let phoneNumber = usersDictionary["phoneNumber"]



                self.posts.insert(eventsStruct (email: email, username: username, phoneNumber: phoneNumber), at: 0)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

                print(eventsStruct.init(email: email, username: username, phoneNumber: phoneNumber))
            }
        })



    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    var homeViewController: HomeViewController?
    //tap to dismiss contacts page
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        dismiss(animated: true) {
            print("dismiss completed")
            let user = self.posts[indexPath.row]

       self.homeViewController?.addBodyguard.setTitle(user.email, for: .normal)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
   //     let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)


        let user = posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = user.username
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = user.phoneNumber

        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func cancelTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



// the HOMEVIEWcontroller containing the button to be renamed

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

 @IBOutlet weak var addBodyguard: UIButton!

  @IBAction func Addguard(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "contactsSegue", sender: nil)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the UIButtons's title in `ContactViewController` you should use delegate to pass this event to `HomeViewController`.

```
protocol ContactSelectionDelegate {
 func contactSelected(email: String) -> Void
}

extension HomeViewController: ContactSelectionDelegate {
 func contactSelected(email: String) -> Void {
   self.addBodyguard.setTitle(email, for: .normal)
 }
}

// In your HomeViewController

@IBAction func Addguard(_ sender: Any) { 
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "contactsSegue", sender: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if (segue.identifier == "contactsSegue")
    {
        let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ContactViewController
        secondViewController.delegate = self
    }
}


// In your ContactViewController
class ContactViewController {

 ....
 weak var delegate: ContactSelectionDelegate?

 ...

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    dismiss(animated: true) {
        print("dismiss completed")
        let user = self.posts[indexPath.row]

   self.delegate?.contactSelected(email: user.email)
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, nothing happened after. The button name still stays the same. no changes occurred.

Comment: I have see your updated code, can't comment otherwise. Maybe share the sample project?

Answer (score 0):

The usual convention in Model-View-Controller designs like UIKit is to not reach from one ViewController into the other.

Instead, there are alternate approaches:

1. Give the class that knows that the new name should be on the button a `delegate` property and make the other controller its delegate and notify it. (others have answered this in detail)
2. Have a shared model object that contains the user name, and have both controllers display their data based on that model object. In that case, your Firebase controller would write the new name to the model, which would make the button's controller notice the property changed and change the button name.
3. Send a `Notification` (using `NotificationCenter`). I wouldn't do that in this case. Notifications are generally best used for things that interest large parts of the application, as anyone can subscribe to them. So they kind of weaken your class's encapsulation. It can also be a bit involved to find all the places that respond to a notification when debugging.